# How to create javascript library which works in both client and server side(Isomorphic)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, isomorphic-javascript

I have already created library using nodejs and webpack is used to bundle it so it can be used on client end.

But if I try to use the bundled file into my node application it doesn't work.
So, how do I create Isomorphic library which will work on both client and server end?

Comment: Just do not use something that does not work with with both sides, or (at least) imitate their work, if you really need them.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a matter of server or client side, that a matter of used module loading system.

As you may already know people out there use **CommonJS** (which node uses), **AMD** (which used on client side to write modular javascript) and or **script tag** (on client side) to load javascript modules. So you should somehow prepare your library to be able to be used with whichever of these module loading systems. As a result there is a **UMD** (**U**niversal **M**odule **D**efinition) pattern which make your module compatible with all of these module systems (See [UMD templates](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) which people use to implement this pattern).

Build and bundling tools (like webpack, browserify, ...) have facilities to bundle your module as a umd, so it's compatible with all module loading systems:

**webpack**:

Set the `libraryTarget` and `library` output configurations:

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './myModule.js',
  output: {
      filename: './dist/myModule.js',
      // export to AMD, CommonJS, or window
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      // set window global to this name
      library: 'myModule'
  }
};
```

**Browserify**:

Use `--standalone` ( `-s` ) option:

```
browserify main.js -s myModule -o myModule.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) by facebook supports Isomorphic component creation that you can use on both client and server side.

Its concept of JSX helps this out.

[Git Hub Isomorphic Example](https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example)

[React with Node for Isomorphic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wfY4TGtMUo)

Isomorphic Javascript Benefits:

- Better overall user experience
- Search engine indexable
- Easier code maintenance
- Free progressive enhancements